# only one tile being drawn xna c#

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, tiles, tilemap

I have been looking at tile engines for the past few days and decided to have a go at my own one for educational purposes. I want to use different textures for the tiles of my map, for example 1 = grass, 2 = sky, 3 = dirt etc.. I am having this problem where the tiles will draw using only one specific texture although I provide multiples. I have been following tutorials here and there and searching online to try and find this problem but to no avail.

In the example below in the LoadContent function I load three different textues into my TileMap object and Console.WriteLine states that there actually are 3 textures loaded into the list.

I was under the impression that the draw method in the TileMap would set the index to the tile ID corresponding to a tile texture and then that specific tile would be drawn on the map in game. for example, index 1 would equal the first texture in the list, index 2 would equal the second texture and so on. 
Is this a correct assumption or am I way off?

Also, can you give me any help/pointers on ways to fix this issue of only one texture showing on the screen.

Thank you in advance.

**Tile Map**

```
 class TileMap
    {
        private MapCell[,] mapCell;
        public const int TILE_WIDTH = 64;
        public const int TILE_HEIGHT = 64;

    private List<Texture2D> tileList = new List<Texture2D>();

    public TileMap(int[,] exisitingMap)
    {
        //initialise this to a new multidimensional array;
        mapCell = new MapCell[exisitingMap.GetLength(0), exisitingMap.GetLength(1)];
        // x always starts on one 
        for (int x = 0; x < mapCell.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapCell.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                mapCell[y, x] = new MapCell(exisitingMap[y, x]);
            }
        }       
     }

    public void loadTextureFiles(ContentManager content, params string[] fileNames)
    {
        Texture2D tileTexture;
        foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
        {
            tileTexture = content.Load<Texture2D>(fileName);
            tileList.Add(tileTexture);
            Console.WriteLine(tileList.Count + " Tile texture count ");
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

        for (int x = 0; x < mapCell.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapCell.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                // setting the index to the tile ID
                int index = mapCell[y,x].TileID;
                Texture2D texture = tileList[index];

                spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle( x * TILE_WIDTH, y * TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT), Color.White);

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

**Map Cell**

```
class MapCell
{
    public int TileID { get; set; }

    public MapCell(int tileID) 
    {
        tileID = TileID;
    }
}
```

**Game1**

```
TileMap tileMap = new TileMap(new int[,]
    {
        { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
        { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
        { 0,1,1,2,1,1,1 },
        { 0,2,1,3,1,3,0 },
        { 0,3,0,3,0,0,0 },
        { 0,0,0,2,0,0,0 },
        { 0,0,0,1,0,1,0 },
    });

 protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        tileMap.loadTextureFiles(Content, "Tiles/Tile1", "Tiles/sky", "Tiles/dirt" );  
    }

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        tileMap.Draw(spriteBatch);
        base.Draw(gameTime);

        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor of MapCell swap tileID with TileID:

```
public MapCell(int tileID)
{
    TileID = tileID;
}
```

Also in the Draw code you need to change:

```
int index = mapCell[y, x].TileID;
if (index > 0) //check if there is a tile
{
    //subtract the index by one to start by the first index, which is 0
    //[0] = tex1, [1] = tex2, [2] = tex3
    Texture2D texture = tileList[index - 1];

    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(x * TILE_WIDTH, y * TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT), Color.White);
}
```